# OSX BigSur, window overlap menubar

Tags: macos, accessibility, macos-bigsur

Folks,
Am probably missing a setting, but how does one allow for windows to be resized larger than where the menu bar is.  Is it possible to allow for menubar to cover open windows?
Effectively when menubar is hidden, am unable to resize the open window to cover the extra space that is free.

What am I missing?  Thanks!

[image: wasted space]

Answer (score 0):

Some applications have the capacity to "Enter Full Screen", usually that option is indicated in the 'View' menu, and has a hotkey associated to it.

Commonly the hotkey should be: {Control} + {Command} + f

At the moment I have Big Sur macOS, this also works: {Ctrl} + {Shift} + f

Same hotkey toggles back out of full screen.